# Glassfish 4.0 No WebSecurityManager found

Tags: glassfish

I just converted a JSF web app to a maven based project. 
I've just compiled it and deployed it to glassfish 4.0. Nothing loads on my page and I get the following log message:

```
[2013-10-03T15:21:24.736+1000] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [realmAdapter.noWebSecMgr] [javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1380777684736] [levelValue: 900] [[

  WEB9100: No WebSecurityManager found for context WEB/WEB]]
```

I'm also using PrettyFaces and Primefaces in my project

Does anyone know what this means or what I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever found a solution here, but I just had the same error when testing out a clustering setup. My solution was to add a web.xml, even though it is optional, it didn't work with out one. I would get the same WARNING and my responses were always empty.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same warning "No WebSecurityManager found for context" and empty html page and in my case the solution was - change the project directory tree:

It was:
hello\
hello\META-INF\
hello\META-INF\ ...some files
hello\src
hello\src\ ...some files
hello\web
hello\web\WEB-INF
hello\web\ *.xhtml files
hello\web\ ...other files

and after I've changed it to that one it started to work:
hello\
hello\META-INF\
hello\META-INF...some files
hello\src
hello\src...some files
hello\WEB-INF
hello\ *.xhtml files
hello\ ... other files

So, I eliminated "web" folder